# Need XSLT on multi-line items

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am a newbie in how to use XSLT. Can anyone please give any suggestions/input/comments on how to use XSLT to convert the following xml to another type of xml output as mentioned below -

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
    <ShowShipment>
    <ApplicationArea>
    <Sender>
    <LogicalID>012345678</LogicalID>
    </Sender>
    <ReceiverId>ABCDEF</ReceiverId>
    </ApplicationArea>
    <DataArea>
    <Show/>
    <Shipment>
    <ShipmentHeader>
    <DocumentID>
    <ID>1700000494-17CCCCC</ID>
    </DocumentID>
    <DocumentReference type="OrderSource" >
    <Type>0001</Type>
    </DocumentReference>
    <DocumentReference type="BillOfLading" >
    <DocumentID>
    <ID>17CCCCC</ID>
    </DocumentID>
    </DocumentReference>
    <ActualShipDateTime>2017-03-29T19:18:01-05:00</ActualShipDateTime>
    <Truck>
    <ID>01</ID>
    </Truck>
    <TrailerNumber>U280</TrailerNumber>
    </ShipmentHeader>
    <ShipmentOrder>
    <ShipmentHeader>
    <DocumentReference type="OMSOrderInfo" >
    <SalesOrderReference>
    <DocumentID>
    <ID>17CCCCC</ID>
    </DocumentID>
    <ReleaseNumber>1</ReleaseNumber>
    </SalesOrderReference>
    </DocumentReference>
    <DocumentReference type="LegacyOrderNumber" >
    <SalesOrderReference>
    <DocumentID>
    <ID>17CCCCC</ID>
    </DocumentID>
    </SalesOrderReference>
    </DocumentReference>
    <DocumentReference type="CustomerReference" >
    <PurchaseOrderReference>
    <AlternateDocumentID>
    <ID schemeName="EDI" >Purchasing Dept</ID>
    </AlternateDocumentID>
    </PurchaseOrderReference>
    </DocumentReference>
    <DocumentReference type="ConsumerPOInfo" />
    <DocumentReference type="DealerPO" >
    <PurchaseOrderReference>
    <DocumentID>
    <ID>10000000</ID>
    </DocumentID>
    </PurchaseOrderReference>
    </DocumentReference>
    <HazardousMaterialIndicator>false</HazardousMaterialIndicator>
    <MultiCartonIndicator>true</MultiCartonIndicator>
    <PrimaryCustomerIndicator>false</PrimaryCustomerIndicator>
    <QACheckIndicator>false</QACheckIndicator>
    </ShipmentHeader>
    <ShipmentUnit>
    <TrackingID>1Z00000000000001</TrackingID>
    <ContainerID>170111111113</ContainerID>
    <DeclaredValueAmount currencyID="USD" >0</DeclaredValueAmount>
    <ShipmentDateTime>2017-03-29T19:15:19</ShipmentDateTime>
    <NetWeightMeasure unitCode="LB" >7</NetWeightMeasure>
    <GrossWeightMeasure unitCode="LB" >7</GrossWeightMeasure>
    <FreightChargeAmount currencyID="USD" >0</FreightChargeAmount>
    <LoadingDateTime>2017-03-29T09:37:04</LoadingDateTime>
    <LoadingWeightMeasure unitCode="LB" >7</LoadingWeightMeasure>
    <Dimensions>
    <WidthMeasure unitCode="IN" >7.75</WidthMeasure>
    <LengthMeasure unitCode="IN" >4.5</LengthMeasure>
    <HeightMeasure unitCode="IN" >11.56</HeightMeasure>
    </Dimensions>
    <ShipmentUnitContainer>
    <ContainerID>ABCD</ContainerID>
    </ShipmentUnitContainer>
    <SSCCode>000005835235</SSCCode>
    <ShipCode>Y</ShipCode>
    <CODAmount currencyID="USD" >0</CODAmount>
    <ShipmentUnitItem>
    <ItemID>
    <ID>900133</ID>
    <RevisionID>900133</RevisionID>
    <VariationID>900133</VariationID>
    </ItemID>
    <UPCID>00000000000000</UPCID>
    <CountryOfOriginCode>US</CountryOfOriginCode>
    <OrderQuantity>5</OrderQuantity>
    <ShippedQuantity unitCode="CT" >1</ShippedQuantity>
    <PurchaseOrderReference>
    <LineNumber>00001</LineNumber>
    </PurchaseOrderReference>
    <SalesOrderReference>
    <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
    <ScheduleLineNumber>1</ScheduleLineNumber>
    <SubLineNumber>1</SubLineNumber>
    </SalesOrderReference>
    <UPCRetailID>814127852</UPCRetailID>
    <ConfirmedQuantity>5</ConfirmedQuantity>
    <CancelledQuantity>0</CancelledQuantity>
    <ItemTypeCode>1</ItemTypeCode>
    <ItemWeight unitCode="LB" >6.33</ItemWeight>
    <HazardousMaterialIndicator>false</HazardousMaterialIndicator>
    <SerialNumberIndicator>false</SerialNumberIndicator>
    <CartonLineNumber>1</CartonLineNumber>
    <PackingSlip>
    <LineText sequence="1" >EDI|00001|20AN17|5|EA||</LineText>
    </PackingSlip>
    <PassThruData qualifier="II" >00001</PassThruData>
    <PassThruData qualifier="KK" >5</PassThruData>
    <PassThruData qualifier="JJ" >EA</PassThruData>
    </ShipmentUnitItem>
    <ShipmentUnitItem>
    <ItemID>
    <ID>900100</ID>
    <RevisionID>900100</RevisionID>
    <VariationID>900100</VariationID>
    </ItemID>
    <UPCID>00000000000000</UPCID>
    <CountryOfOriginCode>US</CountryOfOriginCode>
    <OrderQuantity>5</OrderQuantity>
    <ShippedQuantity unitCode="CT" >1</ShippedQuantity>
    <PurchaseOrderReference>
    <LineNumber>00001</LineNumber>
    </PurchaseOrderReference>
    <SalesOrderReference>
    <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
    <ScheduleLineNumber>1</ScheduleLineNumber>
    <SubLineNumber>1</SubLineNumber>
    </SalesOrderReference>
    <UPCRetailID>814120000</UPCRetailID>
    <ConfirmedQuantity>5</ConfirmedQuantity>
    <CancelledQuantity>0</CancelledQuantity>
    <ItemTypeCode>1</ItemTypeCode>
    <ItemWeight unitCode="LB" >6.33</ItemWeight>
    <HazardousMaterialIndicator>false</HazardousMaterialIndicator>
    <SerialNumberIndicator>false</SerialNumberIndicator>
    <CartonLineNumber>1</CartonLineNumber>
    <PackingSlip>
    <LineText sequence="1" >EDI|00001|20AN00|5|EA||</LineText>
    </PackingSlip>
    <PassThruData qualifier="II" >00001</PassThruData>
    <PassThruData qualifier="KK" >5</PassThruData>
    <PassThruData qualifier="JJ" >EA</PassThruData>
    </ShipmentUnitItem>
    <DropShipIndicator>BBB</DropShipIndicator>
    <BulkItemLocation>301</BulkItemLocation>
    <ListBaseFreightAmount currencyID="USD" >0</ListBaseFreightAmount>
    </ShipmentUnit>
    </ShipmentOrder>
    </Shipment>
    </DataArea>
    </ShowShipment>
```

I would be needing the Output as below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<ShowShipment>
<ApplicationArea>
<Sender>
<LogicalID>012345678</LogicalID>
</Sender>
<ReceiverId>ABCDEF</ReceiverId>
</ApplicationArea>
<DataArea>
<Show/>
<Shipment>
<ShipmentHeader>
<DocumentID>
<ID>1700000494-17CCCCC</ID>
</DocumentID>
<DocumentReference type="OrderSource" >
<Type>0001</Type>
</DocumentReference>
<DocumentReference type="BillOfLading" >
<DocumentID>
<ID>17CCCCC</ID>
</DocumentID>
</DocumentReference>
<ActualShipDateTime>2017-03-29T19:18:01-05:00</ActualShipDateTime>
<Truck>
<ID>01</ID>
</Truck>
<TrailerNumber>U280</TrailerNumber>
</ShipmentHeader>
<ShipmentOrder>
<ShipmentHeader>
<DocumentReference type="OMSOrderInfo" >
<SalesOrderReference>
<DocumentID>
<ID>17CCCCC</ID>
</DocumentID>
<ReleaseNumber>1</ReleaseNumber>
</SalesOrderReference>
</DocumentReference>
<DocumentReference type="LegacyOrderNumber" >
<SalesOrderReference>
<DocumentID>
<ID>17CCCCC</ID>
</DocumentID>
</SalesOrderReference>
</DocumentReference>
<DocumentReference type="CustomerReference" >
<PurchaseOrderReference>
<AlternateDocumentID>
<ID schemeName="EDI" >Purchasing Dept</ID>
</AlternateDocumentID>
</PurchaseOrderReference>
</DocumentReference>
<DocumentReference type="ConsumerPOInfo" />
<DocumentReference type="DealerPO" >
<PurchaseOrderReference>
<DocumentID>
<ID>10000000</ID>
</DocumentID>
</PurchaseOrderReference>
</DocumentReference>
<HazardousMaterialIndicator>false</HazardousMaterialIndicator>
<MultiCartonIndicator>true</MultiCartonIndicator>
<PrimaryCustomerIndicator>false</PrimaryCustomerIndicator>
<QACheckIndicator>false</QACheckIndicator>
</ShipmentHeader>
<ShipmentUnit>
<TrackingID>1Z00000000000001</TrackingID>
<ContainerID>170111111113</ContainerID>
<DeclaredValueAmount currencyID="USD" >0</DeclaredValueAmount>
<ShipmentDateTime>2017-03-29T19:15:19</ShipmentDateTime>
<NetWeightMeasure unitCode="LB" >7</NetWeightMeasure>
<GrossWeightMeasure unitCode="LB" >7</GrossWeightMeasure>
<FreightChargeAmount currencyID="USD" >0</FreightChargeAmount>
<LoadingDateTime>2017-03-29T09:37:04</LoadingDateTime>
<LoadingWeightMeasure unitCode="LB" >7</LoadingWeightMeasure>
<Dimensions>
<WidthMeasure unitCode="IN" >7.75</WidthMeasure>
<LengthMeasure unitCode="IN" >4.5</LengthMeasure>
<HeightMeasure unitCode="IN" >11.56</HeightMeasure>
</Dimensions>
<ShipmentUnitContainer>
<ContainerID>ABCD</ContainerID>
</ShipmentUnitContainer>
<SSCCode>000005835235</SSCCode>
<ShipCode>Y</ShipCode>
<CODAmount currencyID="USD" >0</CODAmount>
<ShipmentUnitItem>
<ItemID>
<ID>900133</ID>
<RevisionID>900133</RevisionID>
<VariationID>900133</VariationID>
</ItemID>
<UPCID>00000000000000</UPCID>
<CountryOfOriginCode>US</CountryOfOriginCode>
<OrderQuantity>5</OrderQuantity>
<ShippedQuantity unitCode="CT" >1</ShippedQuantity>
<PurchaseOrderReference>
<LineNumber>00001</LineNumber>
</PurchaseOrderReference>
<SalesOrderReference>
<LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
<ScheduleLineNumber>1</ScheduleLineNumber>
<SubLineNumber>1</SubLineNumber>
</SalesOrderReference>
<UPCRetailID>814127852</UPCRetailID>
<ConfirmedQuantity>5</ConfirmedQuantity>
<CancelledQuantity>0</CancelledQuantity>
<ItemTypeCode>1</ItemTypeCode>
<ItemWeight unitCode="LB" >6.33</ItemWeight>
<HazardousMaterialIndicator>false</HazardousMaterialIndicator>
<SerialNumberIndicator>false</SerialNumberIndicator>
<CartonLineNumber>1</CartonLineNumber>
<PackingSlip>
<LineText sequence="1" >EDI|00001|20AN17|5|EA||</LineText>
</PackingSlip>
<PassThruData qualifier="II" >00001</PassThruData>
<PassThruData qualifier="KK" >5</PassThruData>
<PassThruData qualifier="JJ" >EA</PassThruData>
</ShipmentUnitItem>
<DropShipIndicator>BBB</DropShipIndicator>
<BulkItemLocation>301</BulkItemLocation>
<ListBaseFreightAmount currencyID="USD" >0</ListBaseFreightAmount>
</ShipmentUnit>
<ShipmentUnit>
<TrackingID>1Z00000000000001</TrackingID>
<ContainerID>170111111113</ContainerID>
<DeclaredValueAmount currencyID="USD" >0</DeclaredValueAmount>
<ShipmentDateTime>2017-03-29T19:15:19</ShipmentDateTime>
<NetWeightMeasure unitCode="LB" >7</NetWeightMeasure>
<GrossWeightMeasure unitCode="LB" >7</GrossWeightMeasure>
<FreightChargeAmount currencyID="USD" >0</FreightChargeAmount>
<LoadingDateTime>2017-03-29T09:37:04</LoadingDateTime>
<LoadingWeightMeasure unitCode="LB" >7</LoadingWeightMeasure>
<Dimensions>
<WidthMeasure unitCode="IN" >7.75</WidthMeasure>
<LengthMeasure unitCode="IN" >4.5</LengthMeasure>
<HeightMeasure unitCode="IN" >11.56</HeightMeasure>
</Dimensions>
<ShipmentUnitContainer>
<ContainerID>ABCD</ContainerID>
</ShipmentUnitContainer>
<SSCCode>000005835235</SSCCode>
<ShipCode>Y</ShipCode>
<CODAmount currencyID="USD" >0</CODAmount>
<ShipmentUnitItem>
<ItemID>
<ID>900100</ID>
<RevisionID>900100</RevisionID>
<VariationID>900100</VariationID>
</ItemID>
<UPCID>00000000000000</UPCID>
<CountryOfOriginCode>US</CountryOfOriginCode>
<OrderQuantity>5</OrderQuantity>
<ShippedQuantity unitCode="CT" >1</ShippedQuantity>
<PurchaseOrderReference>
<LineNumber>00001</LineNumber>
</PurchaseOrderReference>
<SalesOrderReference>
<LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
<ScheduleLineNumber>1</ScheduleLineNumber>
<SubLineNumber>1</SubLineNumber>
</SalesOrderReference>
<UPCRetailID>814120000</UPCRetailID>
<ConfirmedQuantity>5</ConfirmedQuantity>
<CancelledQuantity>0</CancelledQuantity>
<ItemTypeCode>1</ItemTypeCode>
<ItemWeight unitCode="LB" >6.33</ItemWeight>
<HazardousMaterialIndicator>false</HazardousMaterialIndicator>
<SerialNumberIndicator>false</SerialNumberIndicator>
<CartonLineNumber>1</CartonLineNumber>
<PackingSlip>
<LineText sequence="1" >EDI|00001|20AN00|5|EA||</LineText>
</PackingSlip>
<PassThruData qualifier="II" >00001</PassThruData>
<PassThruData qualifier="KK" >5</PassThruData>
<PassThruData qualifier="JJ" >EA</PassThruData>
</ShipmentUnitItem>
<DropShipIndicator>BBB</DropShipIndicator>
<BulkItemLocation>301</BulkItemLocation>
<ListBaseFreightAmount currencyID="USD" >0</ListBaseFreightAmount>
</ShipmentUnit>
</ShipmentOrder>
</Shipment>
</DataArea>
</ShowShipment>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<!-- Need one <ShipmentUnit> for one <ShipmentUnitItem> -->
    <xsl:template match="ShipmentUnitItem">


       <ShipmentUnit>
    <xsl:copy-of select="../TrackingID|../ContainerID|../DeclaredValueAmount|../hipmentDateTime|../NetWeightMeasure|../GrossWeightMeasure|../FreightChargeAmount|../LoadingDateTime|../LoadingWeightMeasure|../Dimensions|../ShipmentUnitContainer|../SSCCode|../ShipCode|../CODAmount|../DropShipIndicator|../BulkItemLocation|../ListBaseFreightAmount|." /> 
</ShipmentUnit>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I could not get to populate ShipmentUnit for each ShipmentUnitItem using the above XSL. I am getting the output as below with an extra ShipmentUnit.

```
<ShowShipment>
    <ApplicationArea>
        <Sender>
            <LogicalID>012345678</LogicalID>
        </Sender>
        <ReceiverId>ABCDEF</ReceiverId>
    </ApplicationArea>
    <DataArea>
        <Show/>
        <Shipment>
            <ShipmentHeader>
                <DocumentID>
                    <ID>1700000494-17CCCCC</ID>
                </DocumentID>
                <DocumentReference type="OrderSource">
                    <Type>0001</Type>
                </DocumentReference>
                <DocumentReference type="BillOfLading">
                    <DocumentID>
                        <ID>17CCCCC</ID>
                    </DocumentID>
                </DocumentReference>
                <ActualShipDateTime>2017-03-29T19:18:01-05:00</ActualShipDateTime>
                <Truck>
                    <ID>01</ID>
                </Truck>
                <TrailerNumber>U280</TrailerNumber>
            </ShipmentHeader>
            <ShipmentOrder>
                <ShipmentHeader>
                    <DocumentReference type="OMSOrderInfo">
                        <SalesOrderReference>
                            <DocumentID>
                                <ID>17CCCCC</ID>
                            </DocumentID>
                            <ReleaseNumber>1</ReleaseNumber>
                        </SalesOrderReference>
                    </DocumentReference>
                    <DocumentReference type="LegacyOrderNumber">
                        <SalesOrderReference>
                            <DocumentID>
                                <ID>17CCCCC</ID>
                            </DocumentID>
                        </SalesOrderReference>
                    </DocumentReference>
                    <DocumentReference type="CustomerReference">
                        <PurchaseOrderReference>
                            <AlternateDocumentID>
                                <ID schemeName="EDI">Purchasing Dept</ID>
                            </AlternateDocumentID>
                        </PurchaseOrderReference>
                    </DocumentReference>
                    <DocumentReference type="ConsumerPOInfo"/>
                    <DocumentReference type="DealerPO">
                        <PurchaseOrderReference>
                            <DocumentID>
                                <ID>10000000</ID>
                            </DocumentID>
                        </PurchaseOrderReference>
                    </DocumentReference>
                    <HazardousMaterialIndicator>false</HazardousMaterialIndicator>
                    <MultiCartonIndicator>true</MultiCartonIndicator>
                    <PrimaryCustomerIndicator>false</PrimaryCustomerIndicator>
                    <QACheckIndicator>false</QACheckIndicator>
                </ShipmentHeader>
                <ShipmentUnit>
                    <TrackingID>1Z00000000000001</TrackingID>
                    <ContainerID>170111111113</ContainerID>
                    <DeclaredValueAmount currencyID="USD">0</DeclaredValueAmount>
                    <ShipmentDateTime>2017-03-29T19:15:19</ShipmentDateTime>
                    <NetWeightMeasure unitCode="LB">7</NetWeightMeasure>
                    <GrossWeightMeasure unitCode="LB">7</GrossWeightMeasure>
                    <FreightChargeAmount currencyID="USD">0</FreightChargeAmount>
                    <LoadingDateTime>2017-03-29T09:37:04</LoadingDateTime>
                    <LoadingWeightMeasure unitCode="LB">7</LoadingWeightMeasure>
                    <Dimensions>
                        <WidthMeasure unitCode="IN">7.75</WidthMeasure>
                        <LengthMeasure unitCode="IN">4.5</LengthMeasure>
                        <HeightMeasure unitCode="IN">11.56</HeightMeasure>
                    </Dimensions>
                    <ShipmentUnitContainer>
                        <ContainerID>ABCD</ContainerID>
                    </ShipmentUnitContainer>
                    <SSCCode>000005835235</SSCCode>
                    <ShipCode>Y</ShipCode>
                    <CODAmount currencyID="USD">0</CODAmount>
                    <ShipmentUnit>
                        <TrackingID>1Z00000000000001</TrackingID>
                        <ContainerID>170111111113</ContainerID>
                        <DeclaredValueAmount currencyID="USD">0</DeclaredValueAmount>
                        <NetWeightMeasure unitCode="LB">7</NetWeightMeasure>
                        <GrossWeightMeasure unitCode="LB">7</GrossWeightMeasure>
                        <FreightChargeAmount currencyID="USD">0</FreightChargeAmount>
                        <LoadingDateTime>2017-03-29T09:37:04</LoadingDateTime>
                        <LoadingWeightMeasure unitCode="LB">7</LoadingWeightMeasure>
                        <Dimensions>
                            <WidthMeasure unitCode="IN">7.75</WidthMeasure>
                            <LengthMeasure unitCode="IN">4.5</LengthMeasure>
                            <HeightMeasure unitCode="IN">11.56</HeightMeasure>
                        </Dimensions>
                        <ShipmentUnitContainer>
                            <ContainerID>ABCD</ContainerID>
                        </ShipmentUnitContainer>
                        <SSCCode>000005835235</SSCCode>
                        <ShipCode>Y</ShipCode>
                        <CODAmount currencyID="USD">0</CODAmount>
                        <ShipmentUnitItem>
                            <ItemID>
                                <ID>900133</ID>
                                <RevisionID>900133</RevisionID>
                                <VariationID>900133</VariationID>
                            </ItemID>
                            <UPCID>00000000000000</UPCID>
                            <CountryOfOriginCode>US</CountryOfOriginCode>
                            <OrderQuantity>5</OrderQuantity>
                            <ShippedQuantity unitCode="CT">1</ShippedQuantity>
                            <PurchaseOrderReference>
                                <LineNumber>00001</LineNumber>
                            </PurchaseOrderReference>
                            <SalesOrderReference>
                                <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
                                <ScheduleLineNumber>1</ScheduleLineNumber>
                                <SubLineNumber>1</SubLineNumber>
                            </SalesOrderReference>
                            <UPCRetailID>814127852</UPCRetailID>
                            <ConfirmedQuantity>5</ConfirmedQuantity>
                            <CancelledQuantity>0</CancelledQuantity>
                            <ItemTypeCode>1</ItemTypeCode>
                            <ItemWeight unitCode="LB">6.33</ItemWeight>
                            <HazardousMaterialIndicator>false</HazardousMaterialIndicator>
                            <SerialNumberIndicator>false</SerialNumberIndicator>
                            <CartonLineNumber>1</CartonLineNumber>
                            <PackingSlip>
                                <LineText sequence="1">EDI|00001|20AN17|5|EA||</LineText>
                            </PackingSlip>
                            <PassThruData qualifier="II">00001</PassThruData>
                            <PassThruData qualifier="KK">5</PassThruData>
                            <PassThruData qualifier="JJ">EA</PassThruData>
                        </ShipmentUnitItem>
                        <DropShipIndicator>BBB</DropShipIndicator>
                        <BulkItemLocation>301</BulkItemLocation>
                        <ListBaseFreightAmount currencyID="USD">0</ListBaseFreightAmount>
                    </ShipmentUnit>
                    <ShipmentUnit>
                        <TrackingID>1Z00000000000001</TrackingID>
                        <ContainerID>170111111113</ContainerID>
                        <DeclaredValueAmount currencyID="USD">0</DeclaredValueAmount>
                        <NetWeightMeasure unitCode="LB">7</NetWeightMeasure>
                        <GrossWeightMeasure unitCode="LB">7</GrossWeightMeasure>
                        <FreightChargeAmount currencyID="USD">0</FreightChargeAmount>
                        <LoadingDateTime>2017-03-29T09:37:04</LoadingDateTime>
                        <LoadingWeightMeasure unitCode="LB">7</LoadingWeightMeasure>
                        <Dimensions>
                            <WidthMeasure unitCode="IN">7.75</WidthMeasure>
                            <LengthMeasure unitCode="IN">4.5</LengthMeasure>
                            <HeightMeasure unitCode="IN">11.56</HeightMeasure>
                        </Dimensions>
                        <ShipmentUnitContainer>
                            <ContainerID>ABCD</ContainerID>
                        </ShipmentUnitContainer>
                        <SSCCode>000005835235</SSCCode>
                        <ShipCode>Y</ShipCode>
                        <CODAmount currencyID="USD">0</CODAmount>
                        <ShipmentUnitItem>
                            <ItemID>
                                <ID>900100</ID>
                                <RevisionID>900100</RevisionID>
                                <VariationID>900100</VariationID>
                            </ItemID>
                            <UPCID>00000000000000</UPCID>
                            <CountryOfOriginCode>US</CountryOfOriginCode>
                            <OrderQuantity>5</OrderQuantity>
                            <ShippedQuantity unitCode="CT">1</ShippedQuantity>
                            <PurchaseOrderReference>
                                <LineNumber>00001</LineNumber>
                            </PurchaseOrderReference>
                            <SalesOrderReference>
                                <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
                                <ScheduleLineNumber>1</ScheduleLineNumber>
                                <SubLineNumber>1</SubLineNumber>
                            </SalesOrderReference>
                            <UPCRetailID>814120000</UPCRetailID>
                            <ConfirmedQuantity>5</ConfirmedQuantity>
                            <CancelledQuantity>0</CancelledQuantity>
                            <ItemTypeCode>1</ItemTypeCode>
                            <ItemWeight unitCode="LB">6.33</ItemWeight>
                            <HazardousMaterialIndicator>false</HazardousMaterialIndicator>
                            <SerialNumberIndicator>false</SerialNumberIndicator>
                            <CartonLineNumber>1</CartonLineNumber>
                            <PackingSlip>
                                <LineText sequence="1">EDI|00001|20AN00|5|EA||</LineText>
                            </PackingSlip>
                            <PassThruData qualifier="II">00001</PassThruData>
                            <PassThruData qualifier="KK">5</PassThruData>
                            <PassThruData qualifier="JJ">EA</PassThruData>
                        </ShipmentUnitItem>
                        <DropShipIndicator>BBB</DropShipIndicator>
                        <BulkItemLocation>301</BulkItemLocation>
                        <ListBaseFreightAmount currencyID="USD">0</ListBaseFreightAmount>
                    </ShipmentUnit>
                    <DropShipIndicator>BBB</DropShipIndicator>
                    <BulkItemLocation>301</BulkItemLocation>
                    <ListBaseFreightAmount currencyID="USD">0</ListBaseFreightAmount>
                </ShipmentUnit>
            </ShipmentOrder>
        </Shipment>
    </DataArea>
</ShowShipment>
```

New Test data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<us:ShowShipment xmlns:us='http://www.ussco.com/oagis/0' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:oa='http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9' releaseID="1.0" systemEnvironmentCode="Production" languageCode="en-US" >
    <us:ApplicationArea>
        <oa:Sender>
            <oa:LogicalID>012345678</oa:LogicalID>
        </oa:Sender>
        <us:ReceiverId>ABCDEF</us:ReceiverId>
    </us:ApplicationArea>
    <us:DataArea>
        <oa:Show/>
        <us:Shipment>
            <us:ShipmentHeader>
                <oa:DocumentID>
                    <oa:ID>1700000494-17CCCCC</oa:ID>
                </oa:DocumentID>
                <oa:DocumentReference type="OrderSource" >
                    <oa:Type>0001</oa:Type>
                </oa:DocumentReference>
                <oa:DocumentReference type="BillOfLading" >
                    <oa:DocumentID>
                        <oa:ID>17CCCCC</oa:ID>
                    </oa:DocumentID>
                </oa:DocumentReference>
                <oa:ActualShipDateTime>2017-03-29T19:18:01-05:00</oa:ActualShipDateTime>
                <us:Truck>
                    <oa:ID>01</oa:ID>
                </us:Truck>
                <us:TrailerNumber>U280</us:TrailerNumber>
            </us:ShipmentHeader>
            <us:ShipmentOrder>
                <us:ShipmentHeader>
                    <oa:DocumentReference type="OMSOrderInfo" >
                        <oa:SalesOrderReference>
                            <oa:DocumentID>
                                <oa:ID>17CCCCC</oa:ID>
                            </oa:DocumentID>
                            <oa:ReleaseNumber>1</oa:ReleaseNumber>
                        </oa:SalesOrderReference>
                    </oa:DocumentReference>
                    <us:HazardousMaterialIndicator>false</us:HazardousMaterialIndicator>
                    <us:MultiCartonIndicator>true</us:MultiCartonIndicator>
                    <us:PrimaryCustomerIndicator>false</us:PrimaryCustomerIndicator>
                    <us:QACheckIndicator>false</us:QACheckIndicator>
                </us:ShipmentHeader>
                <us:ShipmentUnit>
                    <oa:TrackingID>1Z00000000000001</oa:TrackingID>
                    <oa:ContainerID>170111111113</oa:ContainerID>
                    <oa:DeclaredValueAmount currencyID="USD" >0</oa:DeclaredValueAmount>
                    <oa:ShipmentDateTime>2017-03-29T19:15:19</oa:ShipmentDateTime>
                    <oa:NetWeightMeasure unitCode="LB" >7</oa:NetWeightMeasure>
                    <oa:Dimensions>
                        <oa:WidthMeasure unitCode="IN" >7.75</oa:WidthMeasure>
                        <oa:LengthMeasure unitCode="IN" >4.5</oa:LengthMeasure>
                        <oa:HeightMeasure unitCode="IN" >11.56</oa:HeightMeasure>
                    </oa:Dimensions>
                    <oa:ShipmentUnitContainer>
                        <oa:ContainerID>ABCD</oa:ContainerID>
                    </oa:ShipmentUnitContainer>
                    <us:SSCCode>000005835235</us:SSCCode>
                    <us:ShipCode>Y</us:ShipCode>
                    <us:CODAmount currencyID="USD" >0</us:CODAmount>
                    <us:ShipmentUnitItem>
                        <oa:ItemID>
                            <oa:ID>900133</oa:ID>
                            <oa:RevisionID>900133</oa:RevisionID>
                            <oa:VariationID>900133</oa:VariationID>
                        </oa:ItemID>
                        <oa:PurchaseOrderReference>
                            <oa:LineNumber>00001</oa:LineNumber>
                        </oa:PurchaseOrderReference>
                        <oa:SalesOrderReference>
                            <oa:LineNumber>1</oa:LineNumber>
                            <oa:ScheduleLineNumber>1</oa:ScheduleLineNumber>
                            <oa:SubLineNumber>1</oa:SubLineNumber>
                        </oa:SalesOrderReference>
                        <us:UPCRetailID>814127852</us:UPCRetailID>
                        <us:ItemWeight unitCode="LB" >6.33</us:ItemWeight>
                        <us:CartonLineNumber>1</us:CartonLineNumber>
                        <us:PackingSlip>
                            <us:LineText sequence="1" >EDI|00001|20AN17|5|EA||</us:LineText>
                        </us:PackingSlip>
                        <us:PassThruData qualifier="II" >00001</us:PassThruData>
                        <us:PassThruData qualifier="KK" >5</us:PassThruData>
                        <us:PassThruData qualifier="JJ" >EA</us:PassThruData>
                    </us:ShipmentUnitItem>
                    <us:ShipmentUnitItem>
                        <oa:ItemID>
                            <oa:ID>900100</oa:ID>
                            <oa:RevisionID>900100</oa:RevisionID>
                            <oa:VariationID>900100</oa:VariationID>
                        </oa:ItemID>
                        <oa:PurchaseOrderReference>
                            <oa:LineNumber>00001</oa:LineNumber>
                        </oa:PurchaseOrderReference>
                        <oa:SalesOrderReference>
                            <oa:LineNumber>1</oa:LineNumber>
                            <oa:ScheduleLineNumber>1</oa:ScheduleLineNumber>
                            <oa:SubLineNumber>1</oa:SubLineNumber>
                        </oa:SalesOrderReference>
                        <us:ItemWeight unitCode="LB" >6.33</us:ItemWeight>
                        <us:HazardousMaterialIndicator>false</us:HazardousMaterialIndicator>
                        <us:SerialNumberIndicator>false</us:SerialNumberIndicator>
                        <us:CartonLineNumber>1</us:CartonLineNumber>
                        <us:PackingSlip>
                            <us:LineText sequence="1" >EDI|00001|20AN00|5|EA||</us:LineText>
                        </us:PackingSlip>
                        <us:PassThruData qualifier="II" >00001</us:PassThruData>
                        <us:PassThruData qualifier="KK" >5</us:PassThruData>
                        <us:PassThruData qualifier="JJ" >EA</us:PassThruData>
                    </us:ShipmentUnitItem>
                    <us:DropShipIndicator>BBB</us:DropShipIndicator>
                    <us:BulkItemLocation>301</us:BulkItemLocation>
                    <us:ListBaseFreightAmount currencyID="USD" >0</us:ListBaseFreightAmount>
                </us:ShipmentUnit>
            </us:ShipmentOrder>
        </us:Shipment>
    </us:DataArea>
</us:ShowShipment>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried?  What is working, and what isn't working?  Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It would also be helpful if you could specify whether you can only use XSLT 1.0, or if you can use XSLT 2.0 or 3.0.

Comment: I tried the below XSLT but I not finding the correct track.

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
<!-- Need one <ShipmentUnit> for one <ShipmentUnitItem> -->
    <xsl:template match="ShipmentUnitItem">
           <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: I need this in XSLT 1.0

Comment: Please update your question post with your XSL code -- it is very hard to read it in the no-linebreaks format of a comment.  Please also explain **what is working** and **what isn't working**.  Provide details.  And lastly, please delete your duplicate question, [Need XSLT code to translate xml with multi-line items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43457456/).

Comment: Hi.... I updated my post can you please take a look at it. I also deleted my duplicate post.

Comment: Hi.... I updated my XSL with the output I am getting. Can you please help me figure out the issue.

Comment: I see input, desired output, and actual output.  Where is your XSL code?

Comment: Hi... It's under XSLT block.

Answer (score -1):

(Rewritten after question was rewritten)

It has become clear that your basic needs are that each `ShipmentUnitItem` is in its own `ShipmentUnit` parent.  This requires reworking the input structure, where one `ShipmentUnit` may contain multiple `ShipmentUnitItem` children.

In your XSLT code, `ShipmentUnit` is produced twice -- once by the identity rule (the first template), which copies this and then applies templates to all of its children, and then you have a specific template that matches on `ShipmentUnitItem`, which then **also** inserts a `ShipmentUnit` element and again copies over the `ShipmentUnit` children.  This is why you get the unwanted duplication.

To avoid this, you need a template that specifically matches `ShipmentUnit` and specifies different behavior.

The following code works in XSLT 1.0, and produces output XML identical to your sample desired output.

```
<!-- An "identity" template.
    "Identity" here means that the template copies over macthing elements, 
    without changing them. -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- This rule matches on `ShipmentUnit`, and essentially duplicates the `ShipmentUnit`
    structure for each of the `ShipmentUnitItem` children. 
    Since this rule specifically matches `ShipmentUnit`, this takes priority over 
    the less-specific `match="*"` identity template above.  This means that the 
    `ShipmentUnit` element is processed specifically here, and *not* by the 
    identity template. -->
<xsl:template match="ShipmentUnit">
    <xsl:for-each select="ShipmentUnitItem">
        <ShipmentUnit>
            <!-- Instead of manually listing each `ShipmentUnit` element to copy over,
                we just select them in a group - we want to copy every `ShipmentUnit`
                child *except for* any `ShipmentUnitItem` other than the current one.

                The code below uses the `preceding-sibling` axis to grab all the
                sibling elements (i.e., elements on the same level and belonging to 
                the same parent) that come before this `ShipmentUnitItem`, and the 
                `following-sibling` axis to then grab all the elements after it.

                The `name()!=` test makes sure we only grab elements that *aren't*
                `ShipmentUnitItem`, so we avoid unwanted duplication. -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="./preceding-sibling::*[name()!='ShipmentUnitItem']"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="./following-sibling::*[name()!='ShipmentUnitItem']"/>
        </ShipmentUnit>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Can you please look at the below output format.

Comment: <us:ShowShipment>
    .
    .
    .
      <us:DataArea>
      .
      .
      .
         <us:Shipment>
          .
          .
           <us:ShipmentUnit>
               <us:ShipmentUnitItem>
           <us:ShipmentUnit>
               <us:ShipmentUnitItem>
          .
          .
         </us:Shipment>
         .
         .
         .
      </us:DataArea>
      .
      .
      .
    </us:ShowShipment>

Comment: @Maddy, please update your question with the desired output format.  Also, your example output is invalid XML -- please fix that before updating your question.

Comment: Hi, I just updated my output can you please look at it?

Comment: As of now, this answer is not helpful to anyone.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, the answer was to a previous version of this question.  I understand that this answer no longer applies to the edited question.  However, the question itself is in a non-answerable state.  What is your advice for best approach?  1) Delete this answer. 2) Edit it to say something like "Answer TBD, pending required question updates".  3) Something else?

Comment: Your current answer should be deleted. You can always undelete+edit or write a new answer if the OP clarifies the question. _"as of 2017-04-17 11:44 Seattle time"_ even seems to anticipate that the answer will be obsolete at a later time.

Comment: @Eiríkr Útlendi, Hi... I tried this XSL with the data that is mocked before application changes and it worked. But when the data came out of real application I am getting issues. Can you please try with my New Test data. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Maddy, your "New Test data" has namespace prefixes on all the elements.  My sample XSL code above matches on `ShipmentUnit` and `ShipmentUnitItem`, while your new input has `us:ShipmentUnit` and `us:ShipmentUnitItem` instead.  You will need to change the XSL in order to match correctly.